# Webcam not found, but device manager says 'working properly'

Tags: windows-10, drivers, webcam, dell-latitude

I've got a Dell Latitude 12 7275 with Windows 10. My webcam doesn't work, but I can't find out why.

In Windows' Device Manager, a ISP Camera Device shows up. It says 'This device is working properly', but it showing a question mark as well. A bit confusing to me.

[image: This device is working properly]

When I try to use the camera, it shows an error:
[image: We can't find your camera]

I already tried to install other drivers, but I really can' t find them. On Dell's website I couldn't find webcam drivers. How can I install my webcam drivers?

Comment: Can you click on the "Details" tab of the device (in your picture) and select "Hardware IDs". Copy/paste the list to your question so we know precisely what the device is :)

Answer (score 0):

You might try right clicking on the four devices and uninstalling them.  Then try this Dell support page to help diagnose and get drivers:  http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/latitude-7275-laptop/diagnose

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the webcam and the USB components as well. Then clean out your registry.  I found that when I simply uninstalled the drivers and USB references, they all came back on restart, but the webcam still didn't work. But when I cleaned out the Registry using CCleaner, it all came good.
Hope this helps.